# Detecting Android Activity data change

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a built-in method to detect any data change made by the user on an Activity in Android?

I want to prevent saving and syncing to the server when the user opens up an activity but did not change anything on it but tapped on the Save button.

Thank you for your help in advance,

Vincy

Comment: what do you mean by data change in activity? what kind of data?

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain booleans in your code to check if any action like touch or click happened anywhere in your activity, and then while clicking on the save button, you can compare those booleans and decide whether to upload or not.

Comment: thanks for the response.  Yes, I know that approach but I see it as a dirty approach.  By handling this way I have to maintain the state of each and every field in the activity manually.  I was looking for something built in that I have seen in my blackberry development.

Comment: There is no such thing in Android! And you do not have to handle the states of each and every field, just toggle that boolean in the onTouch() and onClick().